# JavaとPostgresに関するエラー

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

参考書「Spring Framework超入門」でPostgresにクイズを登録するコードを書いたのですが、エラーが発生しました。
Javaバージョン：11
PostgreSQL：12

バージョンは参考書通りに合わせているのですが、エラーになりました。

エラー文は

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcDialect' defined in class path resource 

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.relational.core.dialect.Dialect]: Factory 

Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to 

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL:
```

・登録コード
QuizApplication.java

```
package com.example.quiz;


import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import com.example.quiz.entry.Quiz;
import com.example.quiz.repository.QuizRepository;

@SpringBootApplication
public class QuizApplication {
    /** 起動メソッド */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(QuizApplication.class, args)
        .getBean(QuizApplication.class).execute();
    }
    /** 注入 */
    @Autowired
    QuizRepository repository;
    /** 実行メソッド */
    private void execute() {
        //登録処理
        setup();
        //全件取得
        //showList();
        //１件取得
        //showOne();
        //更新処理
        //updateQuiz();
        //削除処理
        //deleteQuiz();
    }
    /** === クイズを２件登録します === */
    private void setup() {
        //エンティティ生成
        Quiz quiz1 = new Quiz(null, "「Spring」はフレームワークですか？", true, "登録太郎");
        //登録実行
        quiz1 = repository.save(quiz1);
        //登録確認
        System.out.println("登録したデータは、" + quiz1 + "です。");
        //エンティティ生成
        Quiz quiz2 = new Quiz(null, "「Spring MVC」はバッチ処理機能を提供しますか？", false, "登録太郎");
        //登録実行
        quiz2 = repository.save(quiz2);
        //登録確認
        System.out.println("登録したデータは、" + quiz2 + "です。");
    }
    
    /** === 前権取得 === */
    private void showList() {
        System.out.println("--- 前権取得開始 ----");
        // リポジトリを仕様して前権取得を実施、結果を取得
        Iterable<Quiz> quizzes = repository.findAll();
        for (Quiz quiz : quizzes) {
            System.out.println(quiz);
        }
        System.out.println("--- 全権取得完了 ---");
    }
    
    /** === １件取得 === */
    private void showOne() {
        System.out.println("--- 1件取得開始 ---");
        //リポジトリを使用して１件取得を実施、結果を取得(戻り値はOptional)
        Optional<Quiz> quizOpt = repository.findById(1);
        //値存在チェック
        if (quizOpt.isPresent()) {
            System.out.println(quizOpt.get());
        } else {
            System.out.println("該当する問題が存在しません・・・");
        }
        System.out.println("--- １件取得完了 ---");
    }
    
    /** === 更新処理 === */
    private void updateQuiz() {
        System.out.println("--- 更新処理開始 ---");
        //更新したいエンティティを生成する
        Quiz quiz1 = new Quiz(1, "「スプリング」はフレームワークですか？", true, "変更タロウ");
        //更新実行
        quiz1 = repository.save(quiz1);
        //更新確認
        System.out.println("更新したデータは、" + quiz1 + "です。");
        System.out.println("--- 更新処理完了 ---");
    }
    
    /** === 削除処理 === */
    private void deleteQuiz() {
        System.out.println("--- 削除処理開始 ---");
        // 削除実行
        repository.deleteById(2);
        System.out.println("--- 削除処理完了 ---");
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/quizdb
springdatasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
```

これはバージョンの違いによるエラーでしょうか？

Comment: プロパティ「`springdatasource.username`」は質問時の誤記でしょうか? (実際には「`spring.datasource.username`」でしょうか?)

Comment: ありがとうございます。コンソールに登録の記述が出ました！ですがデータベースには登録されていませんでした。この時は登録コードである、QuizApplication.javaが関係しているのでしょうか？

Comment: 質問に対し自己解決したのであれば、ご自身で回答を行い承認すると良いと思います。その上で、新たな問題を別の質問にした方が良いと思います。(元の質問とは要旨が異なるように見受けますので)

Comment: 新たに質問する際には、`QuizRepository`の内容と、登録されてないと判断した事象(DBにレコードがない、コンソールに期待する文字が出力されない、等)を記載するのが良いと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。新しく質問をさせて頂きます。

Answer (score 0):

springdatasource.username
↓
spring.datasource.username
へ修正したら実行されました。